# Dynamically add widget by name

Tags: widget, dojo

What if I had a bunch of menu links, each one containing a widget name to load in a center content pane, and a custom widget for each one of them? Can I bind only one time the click event to all menu links then kinda EVAL the widget name and load it? Or do I have to hard code each widget name loading to the corresponding menu link click event?